# operator overloading Error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘some-type’ to an rvalue of type ‘some-type’

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, addition

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace ComplexNumberNamespace
{
    typedef struct _Data
    {
        double real;
        double imag;
    }Data;

    class ComplexNumber
    {
    private:
        Data data{};
    public:
        ComplexNumber();
        ComplexNumber(float real, float imag);
        ComplexNumber(ComplexNumber&);
        string to_string();
        void operator = (ComplexNumber&);
        ComplexNumber operator + (ComplexNumber& rhs);
    };

    string ComplexNumber::to_string() {
        std::string str;
        str = std::to_string(data.real);
        str.append(" + i ");
        str.append(std::to_string(data.imag));

        return str;
    }

    ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(ComplexNumber & rhs) {
        std::cout<<"copy constructor";
        data.real = rhs.data.real;
        data.imag = rhs.data.imag;
    }

    ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber() {
        data.real = 0.0;
        data.imag = 0.0;
    }

    void ComplexNumber::operator=(ComplexNumber &cplx) {
        std::cout<<"assignment operator";
        data.real = cplx.data.real;
        data.imag = cplx.data.imag;
    }

    ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(float real, float imag) {
        data.real = real;
        data.imag = imag;
    }

    ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator+(ComplexNumber &rhs)
    {
        ComplexNumber temp(data.real + rhs.data.real, data.imag+rhs.data.imag);

        return temp;
    }
}

using namespace ComplexNumberNamespace;

int main()
{
    ComplexNumber c1(1, 2);

    ComplexNumber c2(4, 3);

    ComplexNumber sum = c1 + c2;

    std::cout<<sum.to_string();
}
```

**Compiler Output**

```
====================[ Build | all | Debug ]=====================================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.3.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\pc\source\repos\Doxygen\input_cpp_files\cmake-build-debug --target all -- -j 3
Scanning dependencies of target input_cpp_files
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/input_cpp_files.dir/MyCppFile.cpp.obj
C:\Users\pc\source\repos\Doxygen\input_cpp_files\MyCppFile.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\pc\source\repos\Doxygen\input_cpp_files\MyCppFile.cpp:79:28: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'ComplexNumberNamespace::ComplexNumber&' to an rvalue of type 'ComplexNumberNamespace::ComplexNumber'
     ComplexNumber sum = c1 + c2;
                         ~~~^~~~
C:\Users\pc\source\repos\Doxygen\input_cpp_files\MyCppFile.cpp:40:5: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'ComplexNumberNamespace::ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(ComplexNumberNamespace::ComplexNumber&)'
     ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(ComplexNumber & rhs) {
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\input_cpp_files.dir\build.make:83: CMakeFiles/input_cpp_files.dir/MyCppFile.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/input_cpp_files.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

Why is my source code generating this error?

What am I doing incorrectly?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructors and operator overloads taking `ComplexNumber&` as argument need to take `const ComplexNumber&` instead.

This line `ComplexNumber sum = c1 + c2` actually calls your ComplexNumber copy constructor and gives it the `c1 + c2` expression result, which is a temporary ComplexNumber. Since you can't make a non-const reference to a temporary object in C++, you get this error.

Ideally your ComplexNumber class should look like this:

```
struct ComplexNumber {

  // ...

  // Copy 
  ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber& other) { *this = other; } 
  ComplexNumber& operator=(const ComplexNumber& other) {
    if (this != &other) { /* copy your attributes from other to this */ }
    return *this;
  }

  // Move (optional - and not really useful in your case)
  ComplexNumber(ComplexNumber&& other);
  ComplexNumber& operator=(ComplexNumber&& other);

  // Unlike operator= we return a temporary value, 
  // so it's a ComplexNumber indeed (no &)
  // We'll modify neither 'this' nor 'rhs', so mark them const
  ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber& rhs) const;

  ~ComplexNumber();
};
```

More details: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

---

Some tips:

- Don't put `using namespace std` in headers (I guess it's a header)
- `typedef struct _Data { ... } Data;` is the old C notation. You can simply use `struct Type { ... } myObj;`